# Рекурсия с двойной задержкой

Tags: javascript

Я в js не силен, если у кого есть время буду рад помощи.

```
var array =  [

    [5402,13784],

    [73542,13785],

    ]

var i = 0;

function farming() {

    Accountmanager.farm.sendUnits(this,array[i][0],array[i][1]);

    if (i < 2) {

      i++;

    }

    if(i==2){

      i=0;

    // необходимо что бы при совпадении этого условия делалась задержка на 10 минут например. И рекурсия продолжалась дальше.  Пока работает нон стопом, рекурсия делает круг и по новой.

    }
}

setInterval(farming, 500);
```

Пытался нагуглить, но не смог найти.

Comment: @Sneg, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Не вижу здесь рекурсии. но вообще поставьте `setTimeout(farming,time)` в конце функции, в начале напишите `var time=500`, при попадании в условие напишите `time=60000`.  для вашей задачи должно хватить. первый раз вызывайте просто `farming()`

в таком примерно виде

```
var i=0;
farming() {
   var time=500;
   //всякий код
   i++;
   if (i>2) {i=0;time=60000;}
   setTiemout(farming,time);
}
farming();
```

только имейте ввиду, что у вас что в случае timeout что interval - this это глобальный контекст (в браузере - window)

Comment: Решил вопрос таким способом. Но благодарю за ответ.

    var array = [
        [5402,13784],
        [73542,13785],
    ];
    
    (function farming(i, n) {
        Accountmanager.farm.sendUnits(this,array[i][0],array[i][1]);
    
        if (i == n-1) return setTimeout(function () { farming(0, n); }, 10 * 60 * 1000);
    
        setTimeout(function () { farming(i+1, n); }, 1 * 1000);
    })(0, array.length);